# How to get specific json value to append to progressbar boostrap

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a problem getting a specific value to append on my progressbar.

My code is like this:

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>JQueryUI Progressbar with JSON</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="progressbar"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

and my js is like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({ dataType:"json",
        url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/l3gwv", 
            success: function(data){
                $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
                    value: data.ID
                });
                console.log(data.ID);
            }
    });
});
```

I just want to get my selected id to be my progressbar, and my json its look like this :

```
[{"ID":71,"Harga":"2.000.000","Bird_Name":"Eurasian Collared-Dove"}, 
{"ID":82,"Harga":"8.000.000","Bird_Name":"Bald Eagle"}, 
{"ID":93,"Harga":"19.000.000","Bird_Name":"Cooper's Hawk"}]
```

Comment: `data` is an array, so you need `data[0].ID`, or some other index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
    $.ajax({ dataType:"json",
        url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/l3gwv", 
        success: function(data){
            var len = data.length;
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
                    value: data[i].ID
                });
                console.log(data[i].ID);
            }                
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>JQueryUI Progressbar with JSON</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="progressbar"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

`data` is an array so manage it in the loop.

Comment: How can you set multiple progressbar to single element??